# Zend client for Salesforce webservice

Tags: rest-api, soap-api, webservices, php

I am new to Salesforce and Zend. I succeeded to implement a regular php client, but I am struggling to do the same in Zend framework. Does anyone know how to do it? Code example (especialy its location in zend project) will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Viktor

Comment: Zend 1.X or 2.X? Have you checked out [Zend_Soap_Client](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.soap.client.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use http://cloudconnect.com to sync your data w/MySQL, and use standard Zend from there.